# Makefile missing separator but have hard tab

Tags: c, makefile

I have 3 files and I want to make a makefile for them.

*The files are*:

- `polyHeader.c` (This is the file containing all function definitions)
- `polyHeader.h` (This is the header file containing all function declarations/prototypes)
- `polyTest.c` (This is the file that contains main function)

*I have created the following makefile*:

```
polyTest: polyTest.c polyHeader.o
    gcc -Wall -o polyTest polyTest.c

polyHeader.o: polyHeader.c
    gcc -Wall -o polyHeader polyHeader.c
```

*NOTE*: I was unsure if I should also deal with the header file (polyHeader.h) in the makefile or does this even need to be compiled (i.e. will the linker just find it and link to it anyway - I have included it in both the other files using `#include "polyHeader.h"`)

Anyway when I run the make command for the makefile shown above I get the following error:

```
Makefile:2: *** missing seperator. Stop.
```

Can anyone advise me how to sort this out?

Comment: You are going to have problems with the compilation after you get the makefile working; you need to include `polyHeader.o` in the command line that creates `polyTest`.  That's unrelated to your current problem, though.

Comment: Ok Jonathon, thanks for that, out of interest: why do I need to include the .o (object file) in the gcc command?

Comment: Do you have a blank line between the `polyTest:` line and the `gcc` line?  Does it work any better if you remove it?  Is there a blank at the start of that line?

Comment: This isn't a compiler-error, so don't tag it as such.

Comment: You need `polyHeader.o` on the command line because the compiler doesn't know about it unless you tell it about it.  The line before informs `make`, but telling `make` doesn't tell the compiler.  Incidentally, you probably want `polyHeader.h` listed as a dependency on both the lines with colons, though it would be more traditional to build `polyTest.o` separately (like `polyHeader.o`) and then just link the two object files.

Comment: I don't have a blank line between polyTest: and gcc lines? the gcc line is directly underneath the other, i just included one when posting here to increase readability

Comment: @user4225083 Increasing readability is good when it doesn't affect the answer to the question. For example, tabs/spaces are a common issue with makefiles.

Comment: If there's no blank line after the first line, then the trouble is (99% probably) that you have no tab at the start of line 2, the `gcc` line, despite protestations to the contrary in the title of the question.  Show the output of `od -c makefile` or some equivalent hex dump.  I'd have to guess that it has blanks instead of a tab at the beginning, even if you typed a tab as you were creating the file.  (The `:set et` option in `vim` expands tabs into spaces unless you're careful and/or `vim` knows about `makefile`s.)

Comment: Ok thanks, remyabel I will keep that in mind in the future. I have updated the code to the now read the same as above but I have also added the polyHeader.o: polyHeader.h and on the next line I have a tab and then gcc -Wall -o polyHeader polyHeader.h

Comment: I am 100% certain there is a tab at the beginning of each "recipe" line, I used the TAB key and kWrite has displayed a marker to indicate that I have used it. I just used the command you recommended (od -c makefile) and displayed the output and I can see the space is there for the tab

Comment: @user4225083 It should appear as `\t` for tabs.

Comment: Thanks, it did not appear /t so what I did is I opened it in a different editor, I used emacs this time and it worked. So emacs must not expand the tabs into white spaces. So it is actually compiling now. The only problem I have left to deal with is that originally I had all the files in one file and everything compiled and ran perfectly but now that they are split up the compiler is telling me that I have an undefined reference to each of my functions, even though I have included the header file into both my main file and the file that contains the function definitions.

Comment: I told you about that problem (undefined references) in my first comment...

Answer (score 1):

```
polyTest: polyTest.c polyHeader.o
```

This line indicates polyTest depends on polyTest.c and polyHearder.o.
But in this gcc line, I don't see the dependency.

```
gcc -Wall -o polyTest polyTest.c
```

And this gcc line should start with a Tab rather than space.

Answer (score 0):

This makefile seems to be missing certain elements, I
suggest reading http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/
for the details for simple makefile contents

I suggest it be written more like this:

```
// indicate certain targets will never be created
.PHONY: all clean

// get list of source files (wildcard would be an even better method)
SRCS = polyHeader.c polyTest.c

// convert list of source files to list of obj files
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -I.
DEPS = polyHeader.h

// first/default target when not listed on command
all: poly ${OBJS}

// link objects to make 'poly' executable
poly: ${OBJS}
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o poly $(OBJS)  

// compile each source file into a object file
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< 

// target for removing debris from current directory
clean: 
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f poly
```

Comment: It's unusual to put `-c` in the `CFLAGS` variable rather than in the recipe, and `LDFLAGS` is more conventional than `LFLAGS`

Comment: And you need LDLIBS or thereabouts after the object files if LDFLAGS (or LFLAGS) comes before the object files.  Otherwise, your linker scans the libraries, then the object files, and that traditionally/typically does not work.  Also, the `all` target should not normally list `${OBJS}` as a dependency - it depends on `poly` and `poly` depends on `${OBJS}` explicitly.

Comment: Redefining `CC=gcc` is pointless since it already contains the right value, and `CFLAGS` is mixing compiler flags and preprocessor flags that should be in the `CPPFLAGS` variable. `rm -f` should be replace by `$(RM)` **without** defining it.